# Prove that $\bar{E}'\underline{\subset }E'$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to prove this:

$\bar{E}'\underline{\subset }E'$.

Now this is how I look at it:

if I have $ x\in \bar{E}'$, then x must be in $\underline{\subset }E'$.

Now the conditions for being a limit point is:

**def limit point:**
A point p is a limit point of set E if every neighborhood of p contains a point q not equal to p, such that q is an element of E.

**def neighborhood:**
 A neighborhood of p is a set Nr(p) consisting of all q such that d(p,q) < r for some r>0.

**def $E'$** is the set of limit points.

Next we can conclude that there is a y element of $\bar{E}$, hence Y is either an element of E or E' or both. If y is an element of E then we can set d(x,y)

Now if y is an element of $E'$, then y is a limit point hence there is a z element of E such that d(y,z)

Questions:

Is it correct to state:
The final goal is to make sure that d(x,z)

Given that I have imposed that y=z in first case does this follow in the second case.(do I need to work under this assumption)

Comment: If you mean "the closure of a set $E'$ is a subset of $E'$" then take as example $E' = ]a,b[$ the closure would be $\bar{E}' = [a,b]$ but neither $a$ or $b$ belong to $E'$.

Comment: @user8469759 I think the OP meant "The limit points of $\overline{E}$ and $E$ are the same".

Comment: @ALEXANDER What is your definition of $\overline{E}$?

Comment: E bar is the union of E and E' , where E' is the limit points of E

Comment: @ALEXANDER Suppose $p\in (\overline{E})'$ and let $r_1>0$. By definition, there exists an element $q\neq p$ in $\overline{E}$ such that $d(p,q)<r_1$. Hence, either $q\in E$ or $q\in E'$. Also, there is $r_2>0$ such that $B(q;r_2)\subseteq B(p;r_1)$. Notice that if you can find an element $x\in E$ such that $x\in B(q;r_2)$ then you are done. Do you have any reason why such an element must exists?

Comment: @Wore Because q is a limit point of E hence every neighborhood of q contains a x not equal q such that x is a element of E. ? So we only need to choose r2 with some conditions such that B(q;r2) is a subset of B(p;r1) ?

Comment: @ALEXANDER If $q\in E$, we can take $x=q$. Otherwise, is exactly as you said, and finding $r_2$ in terms of $r_1$ and $d(p,q)$ should not be difficult.

Comment: @Wore. Hm seems like I am missing something fundamental as I am not able to construct this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p\in (\overline{E})'$ and let $r_1>0$. By definition, there exists an element $q\neq p$ in $\overline{E}$ such that $d(p,q)<r_1$. Since $\overline{E}=E\cup E'$, we have either $q\in E$ or $q\in E'$.

If $q\in E$ we are done as we have found an element of $E$ which is in $B(p;r_1)$.

Suppose now that $q\in E'$, and take $r_2=\min \{r_1-d(p,q),d(p,q)\}$ (or $r_2=r_1$ in case $p=q$). We have $r_2>0$ and $B(q;r_2)\subseteq B(p;r_1)$ and, by definition of $E'$, there is an element $x\neq q$ in $E$ such that $x\in B(q;r_2)$, and hence, $x\in B(p;r_1)$ as desired.

Comment: I have one question though, in the text book it states that d(p,q)>=d(p,x)-d(p,q)>0, but how is (p,x)-d(p,q)>0 in all cases?

Comment: What the text book states is not true in general with the choices of variables I am using here. To see the differences of the distances can be in ALL cases, I would suggest you to draw some circles...

Answer (score 0):

Assume a in (cl A)' and U open nhood a.
Thus some x in U cap cl A with x /= a.
Let V = U - {a} which is open for T1 spaces including metric spaces.
Since x in V, there is some y in V cap A.  y /= a.
Hence a in A' and (cl A)' subset A'.